# How do I put an array of random dates in chronological order?

Tags: vba, time, date, datediff

I have an array of dates whose format is like this: 10/15/2005 or 2/10/2011.

Let's say the array has 10 dates, some of which may be duplicates.

arrDates(9) 'elements 0-9 represent 1 date

What is the best way to re-arrange the elements so that they are in chronological order?

Comment: I'm not a VB programmer, but I'd imagine that vb arrays are likely to have a `Sort()` method, which will automatically return a sorted array, given that you're using the built-in `DateTime` type.  In C#(part of the .net framework, has a lot of the same functionality) there's an `Array.Sort(myArrayName)` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short lists (arrays) you could use an invisible ListBox, or a fabricated ADO Recordset, or you could hand-code a short sort routine.  Performance usually isn't a big issue until you have larger lists to sort.

Here is an example using a temporary Collection.  It has a similar advantage to that of using a Recordset in that it can carry multivalued items, something that gets clunky fast using multidimensional arrays.  To do that with a Collection you'd create a small Class containing the values (including the sort key) you need to carry along.

This particular approach could be optimized by using a binary search in place of the simple sequential search (the "J loop" here):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim A(9) As String, B(9) As String
    Dim I As Integer, J As Integer

    'Create some data, here we'll use String values but Date,
    'Integer, Double, whatever work as well.
    Randomize
    For I = 0 To 9
        A(I) = CStr(Fix(Rnd() * 100000))
        A(I) = Right$(String$(5, "0") & A(I), 6)
    Next

    'Sort A() as B().  Could just as easily copy the results
    'back into A() instead.
    With New Collection
        For I = 0 To UBound(A)
            For J = 1 To .Count
                If A(I) <= .Item(J) Then
                    .Add A(I), , J
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If J > .Count Then .Add A(I)
        Next

        For I = 1 To .Count
            B(I - 1) = .Item(I)
        Next
    End With

    'Print before and after.
    AutoRedraw = True
    Print "A", "B"
    Print
    For I = 0 To 9
        Print A(I), B(I)
    Next
End Sub
```

Of course with something like a "date" represented as a String value you'd still need to normalize it for sorting as others have mentioned.  Here that is simulated by creating String values based on numbers and padding with leading zeros for normalization.

Comment: I wanted to accept an answer before I had to leave but now that I'm back at my computer I see that there is no Array.Sort.  Bob, you mention an "invisble listbox" option.  What is that?  I want to understand how that method works. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can add a ListBox to your Form, set its properties Visible=False and Sorted=True. Then when running, add your items and once done retrieve them from the List property.  This presumes your VBA host offers a ListBox that works anything like the one in VB6 though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to format them in YYYYMMDD format and then sort them lexically (lexicographically, character by character, in alphabetical order). Maybe a but of a misnomer since we have only digits here, but alas.

Comment: BTW wouldn't it be so much nicer to switch to VB.NET, C# or Java?

Comment: What does "sort them lexically" mean?  I Googled it and I still don't get ("concerning the vocabulary, words or morphemes of a language") how you sort something lexically.  BTW, I'm using VBA in Excel..I shouldn't have tagged VB6..that was a mistake.

Comment: Lexical (the way I meant it at least) means 'in alphabetical order, character by character'. In this case digit by digit. E.g. '02' comes before '10', but also: '10' comes before '2', hence the 'DD' format, changing a '2' into a '02'. Just think of sorting pictures that have a date in the file names by these file names in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

first you should make all dates to have same length (Replacing single digits with 0# format)
you can use Format$ function to format them

[Here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6)'s how you can use it.

Then you can use Array.Sort to sort them

[Here](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-231925.html)'s how you can do it

**Edit:**
Bob was right . The Sort Method of Array is not available in vb6.So I've changed the link to an article that explains how you can write a quick sort algorithm yourself.

Comment: Er, how can this get an upvote, much less be accepted as the answer? It proposes a VB.Net technique that isn't available in VB6.